# Java Conversion into Double

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

```
   class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double b = 1.13f * 100;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

In the Above code when f is not appended to 1.13 the output is 112.99999999999999 but when f is appended to 1.13 the value us 113. Why is this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried the same test using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`?

Comment: im getting the same output 112.99999999999999

Comment: @Nikhil ... because `d` for double (64 bit) is the default and therefore the same as omitting it. That's why *trying* `d` is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `f` suffix is telling Java that the number is a single precision floating point number, instead of a double floating point number.

The problem with floating point numbers in general, is that certain numbers cannot be precisely represented. Each bit of the mantissa of the internal representation represents a fraction with a power of 2 in the denominator, so 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc. Then the computer will select the closest number that represents the number you want.

What is happening in your case is that when you leave out the `f`, it uses the full double precision bits, and gets the closest number to it (112.9999999999). When you do the `f` your are telling the program to round it up to the closest single precision floating point, so the first 9 that doesn't fit gets rounded and propagates up to the value of 113.

It is a bit of a matter of coincidence for this specific number. Don't assume that using single precision floating point will always give you the *expected* result. Floating point arithmetic is always a bit messy in computing.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `f` to the decimal it makes it a `float` constant which has only about 6 digits of precision.  This makes representation error much more likely and much bigger.

When you drop the use of `f`, the decimal is a double which has half a trillion times the precision. This makes the representation error much smaller, and when printed as a `double` you are less likely to see it.

When you print a `double`, the libraries expects there to be some representation error and will show you the simplest/shortest number which has the same representation as the double. (This is actually an infinite number of numbers which map to the same representation)

However, this implicit rounding will only correct a very small amount and is unlikely to correct for the representation error of a `float`.  Note: if you print using a `float` instead of a `double` it will perform greater rounding, hiding the error.

Comment: It's "less likely" according to you, but OP has exactly that case.

Comment: @ThomasWeller perhaps the statement was confusing. I have reworded it.

Comment: this occurs only for values from 1.13 to 1.16 the rest all I get a proper output so say 1.17 is the value multiplied by 100, so I get a value of 117 now which is correct